How to combine use together graphql modules and graphql directives
I create graphql yoga server using modules:
const application = createApplication({ modules: MY_MODULES_ARRAY })

const yoga = createYoga<ServerContext>({
    ...
    plugins: [useGraphQLModules(application)]
    ...
})

According to the directives guide I need to patch a schema:
https://the-guild.dev/graphql/tools/docs/schema-directives
How should I combine directives and modules?
Should I get the schema from application.schema, patch it and then createYoga() with new patched schema instead of modules?

To patch the schema in case of graphql-modules schemaBuilder param needs to be used in createApplication():
const application = createApplication({
    modules: MY_MODULES_ARRAY,
    schemaBuilder: ({ typeDefs, resolvers }) => {
        // Build the schema from modules
        let schema = makeExecutableSchema({
            typeDefs,
            resolvers: resolvers
        })

        // Apply the directive transformer, i.e. upperCaseDirective
        const patchedSchema = MY_DIRECTIVE_TRANSFORMER(schema);

        return patchedSchema;
    }
})


